# how to hide popup window while pw.setfocusable(true)?

Tags: android, gridview, popupwindow, optionmenu

when i open popup window, i can't dismiss it because i used popupwindow.setfocusable(true).if i don't use focsable i can't open item of grid view.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_popup, null);

    gridViewPopup = (GridView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewPopup);

    mCategoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    gridViewPopup.setAdapter(mCategoryAdapter);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

here,i set used focasable(true)

by using this i cant dissmiss popup window on same button

```
if (popupShowing == false) {
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.category_list), 0,
                    0);
            popupShowing = true;
        } else {
            popupWindow.dismiss();

            popupShowing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set **popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);** this is worked for me.

Comment: if i use  popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true); ,click event of grid view item is not detected..